# how to read/write in kafka using jdbc with conditions

Tags: jdbc, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-connect

I have a Kafka server that works fine for sync a table between server. My DB is PostgreSQL and I 'm using JDBC sink/source connector.

Now my question is How can I read data from two table in `Source` and Insert data to Four different table in `Sink` side.

example:

Source table: Users, Roles

Sink tables: Workers, Managers, Employers, ...

In parent server all users are available in `Users` table and have relation with `Role` table. in other side I want to insert data to specific table according to it's role

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the JDBC Sink you need one topic per target table. Thus you need four topics, one per target table, populated with the joined data. This join needs to happen at some point in the pipeline. Options would be :

1. As part of the JDBC Source, using the `query` option of the connector. Build four connectors, each with the necessary query to populate each target topic with the join that is done on the postgres side in SQL.
2. As a streaming application e.g. in Kafka Streams or KSQL. The JDBC source would pull in the source `users` and `roles` tables and you'd perform the join as each record flowed through.

Comment: In solution number one, How we could specify table name because I couldn't find any option to specify table name to insert

Comment: the table name is taken from the topic name, optionally modified as part of the connector using the RegExRouter Single Message Transform